# What is the @linkplain tag used for and how does it differ from @link

Tags: java, javadoc

I am wondering what exactly is the difference of the JavaDoc tags `@link` and `@linkplain`.

They both seem to generate the same html code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It produces different formatting in javadoc
you can try it in IDE:

`{@link #method()}` - monospaced formatting (code)

`{@linkplain #method()}` standard formatting

Example:

[image]

Comment: you are right, the font is different. In my IDE this difference is almost not noticeable.

Answer (score 26):

From Oracle [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html):

[@link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link)

> Inserts an in-line link with visible text label that points to the
>   documentation for the specified package, class or member name of a
>   referenced class. This tag is valid in all doc comments: overview,
>   package, class, interface, constructor, method and field, including
>   the text portion of any tag (such as @return, @param and @deprecated).

[@linkplain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#linkplain)

> Identical to {@link}, except the link's label is displayed in plain
>   text than code font. Useful when the label is plain text.